# Doubly Linked List InsertBack Method problem

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

Alright so for some reason this code is not quite working for my insertBack function for the doubly linked list template class Dlist.

```
template <typename T>
void Dlist<T>::insertBack(T *o)
{
    node *findLast;
    node* newNode = new node;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->prev = NULL;
    newNode->o = o;

    if (first == NULL){
        first = newNode;
        last = newNode;
    } else {
        findLast = first;
        while (findLast->next){
            findLast = findLast->next;
        }
        newNode->prev = findLast;
        last = newNode;
    }

}
```

first and last correspond to the first and last nodes of the Dlist.  My problem is that 'last' is not being assigned to newNode at the end.  When I debug (using VS2010), newNode is correctly assigned the value of the method argument and its 'previous' node is correctly assigned to 'findLast'.  But when I assign last to newNode, nothing happens.

If it's not something immediately obvious, I am happy to post the actual class definition for Dlist, though it is a pretty standard linked list.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Now I feel silly for iterating through the list given that it's a doubly-linked list.

Comment: Note that you would want to implement a singly-linked list the same way. Keeping track of the tail (last) allows for O(1) execution time on appends vs. O(n) if you have to traverse the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a doubly-linked list and you're keeping track of the last node... why are you iterating all the way through it to append to the end?

All you have to do is:

```
node* newNode = new node;
newNode->o = o;
newNode->previous = last;
last->next = newNode;
last = newNode;
```

Comment: Ah.  Thanks so much.  I'm a beginner with Linked Lists, just sort of diving in head first here.

Answer (score 0):

You're lacking a `findLast->next = newNode;`